# ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I have a big problem with ant.

when i try to run android simulator from phpstomr, debug console show me this messagge:

```
/usr/local/bin/phonegap run --emulator android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...

/Users/stopal/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
    at /Users/stopal/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:47:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:652:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
{ [Error: /Users/stopal/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8] code: 8 }
   [error] /Users/stopal/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
```

settings of my ~/.bash_profile

```
export ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant/1.9.4"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Some one can help me?

Comment: you also want to add to PATH android sdk tools and platform-tools paths

Comment: this is my complete bash_profile. Can tell me if it right or not?

export PATH=$PATH:~/Desktop/Sviluppo-Web-E-APP/Android-SDK-Eclipse-Platform/sdk/tools/

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant/1.9.4

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin

Comment: if i try to write 'ant' in my mc terminale, i see this messagge:
'Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher'

any idea for solve it?